# How to using lib*.so that was built in AOSP using mm command

Tags: android, build, android-source

I have `c/c++` source code that was built as shared library using `AOSP environment`. (Using mm command). That has 4 function: `add`, `sub`, `multiple`, `divide`. Now, I want to call these function from Android Application that uses UI. It means that I want to use native library in Android Application. So my question is do I call these functions directly from Android Application? and if so, How I can do that ?

Thank A lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Applications are written in Java, or Kotlin, or whatever language that compiles to DEX (the bytecode that runs in Android JVM). You need JNI layer to connect to your C++ library. Hopefully, your language provides **native** methods that are implemented via JNI.